# How to catch exact exception in wcf service

Tags: c#, wcf, c#-4.0

I want to catch all Faults in WCF service, and found the way to do that

```
OperationContext.Current.Channel.Faulted += delegate(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    //exception is thrwon in wcf service
}
```

the question is how to know the exact exception in Fault event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way would be to use an [error handler](http://blog.wadolabs.com/2009/03/wcf-exception-handling-with-ierrorhandler/) by implementing the [IErrorHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler.aspx) interface.